# How do I calculate the slope in Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)

Tags: statistics

I am following along a [Deep Learning video lesson](https://youtu.be/5L3Ao5KuCC4?t=6409), and at some point the author explains SGD.

He says:
**"First we randomly pick a value, we pick -1.5"**

[image]

**"Now we need to know: If we increase X a bit, does my... Remember that the Y axis is our "loss"... does my loss get a little bit better? Remember that better is smaller... or a bit worse?
So we can do this easily enough: We can pick a slightly higher x and a slightly lower X and see what happens."**

Now he makes a quick jump that I don't understand. He shows a slope, but I don't see how he created it.

**"And you can see: It's just the slope:"**

[image]

**"It's just the slope at this point. It tells you that if I increase X by a bit, then my loss will decrease."**

How did he create the slope?

Did he use for example x= -1.75 and made a dot where it hits the curve, and then he used for example x = -1.0 and made another dot where it hit the curve, and then he drew a line between these hit points, and that is the slope?

And then he goes on to say:

[image]

"Now if we change our weight... our parameter just a little bit in the direction of the slope... so here is the direction of the slope, so here is the value:"

[image]

I don't understand how he determined how long this red line should be.
Is the length the distance between -1.75 and -1.0, so 0.75?

Thank you!

Comment: It will help us help you if you tell us which is your background. In particular, do you know about Calculus?

Comment: @Miguel No, I don't know about Calculus.

Comment: The slope is the derivative, which is the starting point of Calculus. Honestly, I am unable to think of a way to explain the slope otherwise. In fact, the "gradient" in the name of the method is exactly this idea of slope and it is a Calculus concept.

Comment: You would help me most if you would answer my 2 questions. From there, I can "think backwards", not the other way around.

Comment: Have you read the section "An analogy for understanding gradient descent" in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent ?

Answer (score 1):

**How did he create the slope?**

Yes, he took $x=-1.75$ and drew the straight line passing through these two points. *But*... this is not exactly the slope at $x=-1.5$. So he took another point closer, say $-1.6$. That looks better but still. Take now $x=-1.50001$. Almost there. Now have the mental image that the distance to $x=-1.5$ is made as small as you want and you have the real slope at $x=-1.5$. So it is an abstract concept: there are really not two points, but only $x=-1.5$.

**Why did he not make the change longer?**

When we do computations, we leave abstract concepts and go back to the real world: now you *do* have two points, thus an approximation of the slope. Then, if the points are too separated, this is a very bad approximation of the slope. You even risk that the $Y$ increases, instead of doing descent. Then you need a small step. This is good for theory. But in practice, small steps mean you walk slow and you never find the minimum. So you need a trade-off between descent and convergence speed. There is a lot of theory to do this trade-off but to begin with, it works by trial and error.

Comment: Thank you. So he determined the length by himself, correct? The length of the red line in the screenshots is the step width, correct?

Comment: Essentially by trial and error.

Comment: I thought the red line's length was the distance between -1.75 and -1.0 = 0.75. But it's not like that, correct?

Comment: Can you please not dive into the concepts of SDG yet? Can you please just answer my newbie questions about the length without any further insights (I can not yet handle them, I first need to have my basic questions solved).

Comment: I am not sure because I have not seen the video and the plot does not have marks in the axes, but yes, the red line is the distance to the $x$ "close" to the starting point, but not so close your are not advancing fast enough.